# why algebraic numbers are periods?

Tags: nt.number-theory

In Kontsevich and Zagier paper, they define a period as a complex number that can be expressed as an integral of algebraic function over an algebraic domain. Then how do we show that all algebraic numbers are period?

Comment: For a real algebraic number, we can just integrate the constant $1$ function over an interval of that length.

Comment: The question is more interesting if you define periods as integrals of rational functions over a domain given by inequalities with rational coefficients. :)

Comment: I only know that by integrating 1 over an interval works for highly symmetric examples, like $2\sqrt{2}=\int_{x^2-2\leq 0}1 dx$, but for degree three or higher degree polynomial, I have no idea how to choose the rational function defining the domain for integration. It seems that we should choose a domain to break Galois symmetry.

Comment: I thought that we were allowed arbitrary finite systems of inequalities? In this case, if $\alpha$ is a root of some polynomial, you can zero in on that root with some other additional rational inqualities, to exclude the other roots of that polynomial.